# Replace characters using re.sub - keep one character

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to repair broken email records in a table. There are emails, for example: 'google@google.comyahoo@yahoo.com' but there can be a single email like 'google@google.com'. The best way to make this correct is in my opinion to use re.sub. But there is a little problem. If there is a record:

`email = 'google@google.comyahoo@yahoo.com'`

I can't simply do replace('.com','.com, ') because it affects both '.com' substrings. So I want to use `re.sub('.com\w', '.com, \w',email)` which replaces only those '.com' substrings, which aren't in the end of the record. The problem is that I want to keep a \w value there.

`print re.sub('.com\w', '.com, \w',email)`

```
>>> google@google.com, \wahoo@yahoo.com
```

instead of

```
>>> google@google.com, yahoo@yahoo.com
```

Can anybody give me an advice how to make it work? (I want to separate emails by comma and space)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capturing group and backreference the group inside of the replacement call:

```
>>> import re
>>> email = 'google@google.comyahoo@yahoo.com'
>>> re.sub(r'\.com(\w)', '.com, \\1', email)
'google@google.com, yahoo@yahoo.com'
```

[Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) recall what was matched by a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html). A backreference is specified as a backslash (`\`); followed by a digit **indicating the number of the group** to be recalled.

Answer (score 2):

```
x="google@google.comyahoo@yahoo.com"
print re.sub(r"(?<=\.com)(?=\w)",", ",x)
```

Output:`google@google.com, yahoo@yahoo.com`

use `lookarounds`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/48

> Lookarounds don't consume any of the string. They are just assertions. When you use them, you need not replace the consumed string back like the above answer does.