# regular expression replace '1-3' format with 'from 1 to 3' format

Tags: python, regex

I am inexperienced with regular expressions and need to know the following:
I have a sentence:

> "Repeat these steps 1-3 times and read the chapters 10-12 followed by 100-150 push-ups"

How do I replace this with:

> "Repeat these steps from 1 to 3 times and read the chapters from 10 to 12 followed by from 100 to 150 pushups"

So the regular expression that I tried to use to identify the format 'digit-digit' is as follows:

```
r'\d\D\d'
```

where the \d's represent single digits and the \D represents a non-digit.
But this only identifies the '1-3'... how can I get a regex that will take any number from 1-1000 and then the hyphen?
Overall how do I replace any number followed by a hyphen with the 'from to' format shown above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace characters using re.sub - keep one character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450475/replace-characters-using-re-sub-keep-one-character)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\d+` to match more than one digits, here `+` means one or more; And then you can capture the digits pattern with parenthesis, use back reference to reformat the pattern the way you need:

```
import re
re.sub(r"(\d+)-(\d+)", r"from \1 to \2", "Repeat these steps 1-3 times and read the chapters 10-12 followed by 100-150 push-ups")
# 'Repeat these steps from 1 to 3 times and read the chapters from 10 to 12 followed by from 100 to 150 push-ups'
```

---

A more strict quantifier than `+` might be `{1,4}` which matches one to four digits as commented by @NolenRoyalty. so you can use `(\d{1,4})-(\d{1,4})` as well depending on your need.

Comment: `{1,4}` might be more appropriate than `+` since the user asked for "any number from 1-1000" (more generally of course this answer is correct)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a quantifier like `+` which means 1 to * times.
`r'\d+\D\d+'`

Or as @Nolen Royalty suggested use  `{1,4}` like `r'\d{1,4}\D\d{1,4}` so you just allow 1 to 4 digits